# C# datagrid duplicate the columns when I try to get the data from database table

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, material-design, dataadapter

the code to get the database and show it on the **datagrid** in this image
[image: image My Code]

datagrid wpf design 
[image: image My DataGrid WPF]

the result 
[image: image Result]

as shown in the image it duplicate the columns ,one with renamed headers and the other one with same headers from database table

I just want those with renamed headers without duplicate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set AutoGenerateColumns to false.
You have prepared your columns in xaml so you do not want to code generate them for you

Answer (score 1):

Use AutoGenerateColumns = "false".

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns = "false">
```